# Modal state not being set to closed after history.push in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-modal

I have a slider that contains "Events" cards, and when the user clicks on a card a modal shows up. And inside the modal, there's a button that redirects the user to a registration form.

I'm using [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal).

The problem is that when the user clicks on the button, the scroll bar disappears. And my conclusion is that the modal state is still set as open after changing the current page.

Here is an extracted code of the News component and inside of it you'll find the modal:

```
import Modal from "react-modal";


function News() {
const [modalIsOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);

const closeModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };
 return (
     <Button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true}>
       Open Modal
     </Button>

        <Modal
          className="modal-class"
          isOpen={modalIsOpen}
          onRequestClose={closeModal}
        >

        <EventDetail 
            onCloseModal={
                () => setIsOpen(false), 
                modalIsOpen
            }
        />

        </Modal>
 )
}
```

this is the EventDetail :

```
function EventDetail (onCloseModal) {

const navigateToRegistrationForm = () => {
    console.log(onCloseModal);
    history.push(`${baseUrl}/registrationForm/${form.id}`) ;
}
 return (

   <Button onClick={navigateToRegistrationForm}>
       Register
   </Button>

 )
}
```

The console.log returns "true" which means the modal is still set as open. How Can I change its state when the "navigateToRegistrationForm" function is called?

Comment: try adding useEffect listening for updates on history object and close modal there

Comment: yeah how can I change the state of the parent component (Modal) inside the child component (EventDetail)

Comment: Well thats even easier and you are actually pretty close to achieving this. Simply pass `closeModal` function from News component down to EventDetails like so `<EventDetail onCloseModal={closeModal} />` and then call it inside `navigateToRegistrationForm`

Comment: That's it! it works now! Thanks!

Comment: @JSEvgeny you can add it as an answer to this question so that I can close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close to achieving this. All you need is basically pass `closeModal` function down to `EventDetail` component like so:

`<EventDetail onCloseModal={closeModal} />` and then call it inside `navigateToRegistrationForm`